# Storing column values and then setting values in another column based on stored valules

Tags: excel, vba

I want to store values under column F and then compare those values to column B based on below conditions:

If value in column F is '2 - High', set value of corresponding cell under column B to 'High'

If value in column F is '3 - Medium', set value of corresponding cell under column B to 'Medium'

If value in column F is '4 - Low', set value of corresponding cell under column B to 'Low'

If value in column F is '1 - Critical', set value of corresponding cell under column B to 'Very High'

If value in column F is '2 - Blocker', set value of corresponding cell under column B to 'Very High'

My code is:

```
Sub ExcelMacro()
    Dim ColumnFArray As Variant, ColumnB As Variant
    ColumnFArray = Range("F5:F1000").Value
    If Sheet1.Range("F5:F1000").Value = "2 - High" Then
        Set ColumnB.Value = "High"
    ElseIf ColumnF = "3 - Medium" Then
        Set ColumnB.Value = "Medium"
    ElseIf ColumnF = "4 - Low" Then
        Set ColumnB.Value = "Low"
    ElseIf ColumnF = "1 - Critical" Then
        Set ColumnB.Value = "Very High"
    Else
        Set ColumnF.Value = "Very High"
    End If
End Sub
```

I've attached the image below for reference
[image]

[Date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1K0th.png)
[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like your code got pasted into the question correctly - it just says `[Excel Macro]`.  Can you edit the question and try the copy/paste again please.

Comment: I'll paste that into your question.

Comment: I just added my code to the question. I am getting a type mismatch error (13) when try to run the code

Comment: If I add new rows to the above worksheet is there a way I can put in a loop which can go through the column F and see if there is value and then set corresponding value in column B based on condition. If no value is present in column F exit the loop

Comment: Does this have to be a macro? Could very easily be done with cell formulas...

Comment: That right. it can be done using formula but I have around 20 steps that need to be performed on the data and I thought it would be better to do these steps as a macro rather than manual work

Answer (score 1):

You will be getting errors because

- you are using a variable called `ColumnF` which has not been declared, nor assigned a value,
- you are trying to use a `.Value` property on an array (which is not an object and therefore doesn't have properties),
- you haven't dimensioned the size of your `ColumnB` array, and
- you are trying to `Set` values in `ColumnB` but, because it is not an object, they need to be `Let` (which is the default).

You also are not performing any sort of loop.

A refactored version of your code, making minimal changes would be, something like:

```
Sub ExcelMacro()
    Dim ColumnFArray As Variant, ColumnB As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    ColumnFArray = Range("F5:F1000").Value
    ReDim ColumnB(1 To UBound(ColumnFArray, 1), 1)
    For r = 1 To UBound(ColumnFArray, 1)
        If ColumnFArray(r, 1) = "2 - High" Then
            ColumnB(r, 1) = "High"
        ElseIf ColumnFArray(r, 1) = "3 - Medium" Then
            ColumnB(r, 1) = "Medium"
        ElseIf ColumnFArray(r, 1) = "4 - Low" Then
            ColumnB(r, 1) = "Low"
        ElseIf ColumnFArray(r, 1) = "1 - Critical" Then
            ColumnB(r, 1) = "Very High"
        Else
            ColumnB(r, 1) = "Very High"
        End If
    Next r
    Range("B5:B1000").Value = ColumnB
End Sub
```

---

However, I think your use of `Variant` arrays is possibly a bit of overkill in this code, so I would recommend something like:

```
Sub ExcelMacro()
    Dim result As String
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 5 To 1000
        Select Case Sheet1.Cells(r, "F").Value
            Case "2 - High"
                result = "High"
            Case "3 - Medium"
                result = "Medium"
            Case "4 - Low"
                result = "Low"
            Case Else
                result = "Very High"
        End Select
        Sheet1.Cells(r, "B").Value = result
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that I used a `Select Case` statement, rather than a `If` `ElseIf` `ElseIf` `ElseIf` `Else` `End If` structure - it just seems easier to read in my opinion.

---

You may also find it useful to replace `1000` with `Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row` - that will mean the loop only goes to the last non-empty cell in column F.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was a huge help. This works now:-)

Comment: Also I want to copy and paste Column E to Column B (when column B is blank). This code will execute before the above code that you gave me

Comment: Why would you copy column E to column B, only to have that value immediately overwritten by a value determined by what is in column F ??

Comment: I think you are right. I doubled checked I steps and it doesn't make sense to do copy step. I appreciate your help

Comment: But in case I would have needed that what would be the code that would have helped me out?

Comment: @rajdeepmahal - You could have added `If IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(r, "B").Value) Then Sheet1.Cells(r, "B").Value = Sheet1.Cells(r, "E").Value` just inside the `For r = 5 To 100` loop.

Comment: Thank you - How do I set a format of column with multiple rows to the following date format MM/DD/YYY. I have attached screenshot in my questioon

Comment: @rajdeepmahal - that sounds like a completely different question.  To assist people searching for answers in the future, please raise a new question.  (Or google `Excel VBA Range.NumberFormat property`.)